# XSLT sort by an element named in XML

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Is it possible in XSLT-1.0 to sort by a value in the xml. In the example below the `<examples>` has requested that that the list of `<example>`s be sorted by the `year` field.

```
...
<examples>
  <sortby>year</sortby>

  <example>
    <year>2012</year>
    <number>3</number>
  </example>

</examples>
...
```

A static conditional using choose does not work in this case as I will not know what the possible fields in `<example>` will be.

Comment: It's possible using [xsl:sort](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#sorting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, use something of this form**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="example">
  <xsl:sort select="*[name()=sortby]" data-type="{sort-data-type}" 
            order="{sort-order}" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

**Do note** that you need to also specify the sort data-type and order.

**Complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="example">
      <xsl:sort select="*[name()=/*/sortby]" data-type="{/*/sort-data-type}"
                order="{/*/sort-order}" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="example">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<examples>
    <sortby>year</sortby>
    <sort-data-type>number</sort-data-type>
    <sort-order>descending</sort-order>
    <example>
        <year>2008</year>
        <number>3</number>
    </example>
    <example>
        <year>2012</year>
        <number>2</number>
    </example>
    <example>
        <year>2010</year>
        <number>5</number>
    </example>
</examples>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<examples>
   <example>
      <year>2012</year>
      <number>2</number>
   </example>
   <example>
      <year>2010</year>
      <number>5</number>
   </example>
   <example>
      <year>2008</year>
      <number>3</number>
   </example>
</examples>
```

If the same transformation is applied on this XML document (the same as above, but with changed `sortby` and `sort-order`):

```
<examples>
    <sortby>number</sortby>
    <sort-data-type>number</sort-data-type>
    <sort-order>ascending</sort-order>
    <example>
        <year>2008</year>
        <number>3</number>
    </example>
    <example>
        <year>2012</year>
        <number>2</number>
    </example>
    <example>
        <year>2010</year>
        <number>5</number>
    </example>
</examples>
```

**then again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<examples>
   <example>
      <year>2012</year>
      <number>2</number>
   </example>
   <example>
      <year>2008</year>
      <number>3</number>
   </example>
   <example>
      <year>2010</year>
      <number>5</number>
   </example>
</examples>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The `select` attribute of `xsl:sort` can contain any XPath expression, so we can specify an expression that selects any child of the elements to be sorted, such that its name is the result of evaluating another XPath expression.
2. In XSLT, typically, all attributes other than `select` allow **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)**s (Attribute Value Templates) to be specified in their values.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by `*[local-name() = $your-sort-item]`, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="examples">
  <xsl:variable name="sort-name" select="sortby"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="example">
    <xsl:sort select="*[local-name() = $sort-name]"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the node on which you sort should be dynamic, read from the `examples/sortBy` node. This being the case:

```
<xsl:template match="examples">
    <xsl:apply-templates select='example'>
        <xsl:sort
            select='*[name() = /examples/sortby]'
            data-type='number'
            order='descending' 
        />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match='example'>
    <p><xsl:value-of select='year' /></p>
</xsl:template>
```

Runnable demo at [this XML Playground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/WH2LW9).

That outputs each year, each as a paragraph. Change 'descending' to 'ascending' as required.